# Validate select dropdown with javascript

Tags: javascript, forms

I'm having trouble with validating my dropdown list with javascript. What I want is to display an error message underneath the field inside span tags if the user hasn't selected any options. I've checked almost every tutorials out there but no luck.

Here is the code for the form:

```
<form name="subform" id="subform" action="submit.php" onsubmit="return checkForBlank()" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">

    <div class="md-form">
        <input type="text" id="subcim" name="subcim" class="form-control"><span class="error_form" id="subcim_error_message"></span>
        <label for="subcim" class="">Title</label><br>
    </div>

<div class="md-form">
    <select class="mdb-select" id="subcat" name="subcat"><span class="error_form" id="subcat_error_message"></span>
        <option value="0" selected>Please select an option</option>
        <option value="option1">Option 1</option>
        <option value="option2">Option 2</option>
    </select>
    <label id="subcat_info">Category</label><br>
    </div>

<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block">Submit</button>
</form>
```

and here is the Javascript code (the first if statement validates the input field in the form:

```
function checkForBlank() {
if(document.getElementById("subcim").value == "") {
    document.getElementById("subcim_error_message").textContent="You must add a title!";
    return false;
} else if(document.getElementById("subcim").value.length < 5 || document.getElementById("subcim").value.length > 80) {
    document.getElementById("subcim_error_message").textContent="The title must be between 5 and 80 characters!";
    return false;
}

var result = document.getElementById('subcat').value;
if (result === "0") {
    document.getElementById("subcat_error_message").textContent="You must select an option!";
    return false;
}
}
```

I'm using

```
 onsubmit="return checkForBlank()"
```

inside the form tag.

When I submit the form without selecting an option, the form seems to be submitted properly, but it does not display the error message.

Any help is appreciated

Comment: Try putting an blank alert to check weather your function is being called or not? And also if possible change `textContent` to `innerHTML`. And please Provide whole code for form like where you put submit button and also how you put onsubmit event also.

Comment: Added the whole code. I checked it with only alert. If I replace this     document.getElementById("subcat_error_message").textContent="You must select an option!"; with an alert, the alert works. The innerHTML doesn't have any effect.

Comment: I just came to realize that the place where you put your span is wrong. You can't put your span inside your select tag. It should be out side your select tag. Just do that much change and your code will just work fine.

Comment: Thanks, that was the problem

Answer (score 4):

```
    function Validate() {
        var subcat= document.getElementById("subcat");
        if (subcat.value == "") {
            //If the "Please Select" option is selected display error.
            alert("Please select an option!");
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }


    onsubmit ="return Validate()"
```

Comment: Change your html code set "" or leave blank in first option value

Answer (score 1):

```
  function Validate() {
        var subcat= document.getElementById("subcat");
        if (subcat.value == "0") {
            //If the "Please Select" option is selected display error.
            alert("Please select an option!");
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }


    onsubmit ="return Validate();"
```

Comment: Thanks, but I don't want an alert message, I'd like to display a text message underneath the field.

Comment: yes you can display text message instead of alert. you just need to paste your text content there.

Answer (score 0):

Change your syntex from

```
<div class="md-form">
    <select class="mdb-select" id="subcat" name="subcat"><span class="error_form" id="subcat_error_message"></span>
        <option value="0" selected>Please select an option</option>
        <option value="option1">Option 1</option>
        <option value="option2">Option 2</option>
    </select>
    <label id="subcat_info">Category</label><br>
</div>
```

To syntex as below

```
<div class="md-form">
    <select class="mdb-select" id="subcat" name="subcat">
        <option value="0" selected>Please select an option</option>
        <option value="option1">Option 1</option>
        <option value="option2">Option 2</option>
    </select>
    <span class="error_form" id="subcat_error_message"></span>
    <label id="subcat_info">Category</label><br>
</div>
```

The only mistake that you are doing is putting your error span within your select tag it self which is not a predefined `HTML` format for `select` tag. As you can see that after putting your `span` tag out side your `select` tag every thing will work as you want.

Answer (score 0):

> **Html**

```
<div class="md-form">
        <select class="mdb-select" id="subcat" name="subcat">
            <option value="0" selected>Please select an option</option>
            <option value="option1">Option 1</option>
            <option value="option2">Option 2</option>
        </select>
<span class="error_form" id="subcat_error_message"></span>
        <label id="subcat_info">Category</label><br>
        </div>
```

> JavaScript

```
function Validate() {
                    var subcat= document.getElementById("subcat");
                    if (subcat.value == "0") {
                        //If the "Please Select" option is selected display error.
                    document.getElementById("subcat_error_message").innerHTML="Error Message";    
    //OR
               document.getElementById("subcat_error_message").textContent="Error Message"; 
        return false;
                    }
                    return true;
                }

                onsubmit ="return Validate();"
```